# How to set MKMapView view angle and turn off 3D building?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am currently working on a navigation app. Is there a way to set view angle in MapKit? I know Google Map iOS SDK has it as one of parameter in viewing camera that you could set, but I wasn't able to find it in MapKit.

Also is there a bool value to turn off 3D building? They are kind of annoying for a navigation app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm looking for it as well.

Answer (score 12):

Add in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.mapView.pitchEnabled = YES;   
self.mapView.pitchEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        self.mapView.showsBuildings = false
```

(swift code) Turns off buildings.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

```
mapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `pitch` to provide viewing angle. For example, `mapview.pitch` or `mapview.camera.pitch` depending on whether you are using a camera or not. Also, set showsbuildng to NO.

Comment: MKMapView don't have any pitch property. Only MKMapCamera has it.